# Cannot build an app when there is CommonJS instead of ES6 module exports/imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, commonjs

I generated a simple app through `create-react-app` (v3.3.0 for what that is worth) without messing with it's default settings.

For the most part, I use I do exports using the ES6 syntax:

```js
export default myStuff

// Or

export const myStuff = ()=>{}
```

However, I wanted one of my scripts to also run in node's CLI. Because of this, some select files use the commonJS syntax:

```js
module.exports = myStuff
```

That is all fine and well, until I decided to build and deploy the app, which then complains that `myStuff` is not being imported if I use the commonJS syntax, the error I get is precisely:

> Creating an optimized production build...
> Failed to compile.
> Attempted import error: 'myStuff' is not exported from './myStuff'.

I should point out that the build and dev scripts were left with whatever was generated by `create-react-app`. Precisely:

```json
...
  "dev": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
...
```

Keep in mind that when running locally both on the Browser and using the Node CLI everything works perfectly. Did I miss something? How could I build with the existing CommonJS files?

Edit: To clarify the question asked by @JustRaman, my usage of these exports within the client app starts with an `index.js` file which lives in the same folder. Think of it as the following:

```
├── ...
├── lib
│   ├── myCommonJSStuff.js
│   ├── myOtherCommonJSStuff.js
│   ├── myEs6Stuff.js
│   └──  index.js
```

From `myCommonJSStuff.js` I do the export as follows:

```js
function myCommonJSStuff () { /* Do Stuff*/ }
module.exports = {
  myCommonJSStuff,
  someOtherIrrelevantFunction
}
```

From `myOtherCommonJSStuff.js` it would just be the a single default export equivalent:

```js
module.exports = function myOtherCommonJSStuff() { /*Do more stuff*/ }
```

For `myEs6Stuff.js` as its name suggest, I use ES6 syntax:

```js
export default function myEs6Stuff () { /*More stuff*/ }
```

Finally, `index.js` I re-export everything so that I can just import it from my `lib/` folder:

```js
import { myCommonJSStuff } from './myCommonJSStuff'
import myOtherCommonJSStuff from './myOtherCommonJSStuff'
import myEs6Stuff from './myEs6Stuff'

export {
  myCommonJSStuff,
  myOtherCommonJSStuff,
  myEs6Stuff
}
```

Comment: are you importing like this `import * as MyStuff from './myStuff'` or `const myStuff = require('./myStuff')`

Comment: I initially import it into an index.js file to re-export them, where I do `import { myStuff } from './myStuff`` and for another file I do `import myOtherStuff from './myOtherStuff'`. Not sure if that makes sense, so I'll update my original post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a similar issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6163 seems like there is no easy solution except ejecting.

1. you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired if you don't want to eject CRA.
2. Another solution can be a module loader to load ESM files in Node https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm this package can help.